# fs mkdir/copy intermittently fails in protected directory, despite having permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, electron, sudo, node.js-fs

I have an electron app on Mac with full disk permissions. I am using fs to make a directory in a protected folder, and copy files from a temp folder to the new directory.

When using `fs.copy`, I periodically get two different types of errors:

- If the directory already exists and is owned by the user:

  - EPERM errors (operation not permitted, unlink xxx) when attempting to overwrite the existing directory, specifically when replacing a manifest.json file. This is very intermittent.
- If the directory does not exist or is owned by root:

  - EACCES errors when attempting to make the directory or copy files to the new location.

Code:

```
[...Array(sourceDirs.length).keys()].map(async (idx) => {
    try {
        await fs.ensureDir(destPaths[idx]);    
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('Directory does not exist and could not be created');
    }
    try {
        await fs.copy(sourceDirs[idx], destPaths[idx]);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('Copy error:', e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I determined that the directory's R/W permissions varied based on what entity created the directory. Some elements of the directory and its children were owned by root, and `everyone` only had read permissions, while other folders were owned by `everyone` and had write permissions.

Programmatically, the only way to solve this was by spawning a chmod command with sudo to update the permissions. In my case, there isn't any issue with taking ownership of the directory.